# Create column with incremental count based on boolean value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column of booleans as shown below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1":[False,True,True,False,False,True,True,True,False]})

    col1
0  False
1   True
2   True
3  False
4  False
5   True
6   True
7   True
```

I want to create a new column that has incremental numbers wherever there is False and forward filled when True, the output should look like,

```
    col1  col2
0  False     1
1   True     1
2   True     1
3  False     2
4  False     3
5   True     3
6   True     3
7   True     3
8  False     4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pd.Series.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) and [`pd.Series.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html)

```
df['col2']=df['col1'].eq(False).cumsum()
```

---

Same as:

```
df['col2']=(~df['col1']).cumsum()
```

---

Output:

```
df
    col1  col2
0  False     1
1   True     1
2   True     1
3  False     2
4  False     3
5   True     3
6   True     3
7   True     3
8  False     4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n = 0

for i, e in enumerate(df['col1']):
    if e==False:
      n +=1
    df.at[i,'OUT']=n
df['OUT'] = df['OUT'].astype(int)
df
```

Output:

```
    col1    OUT
0   False   1
1   True    1
2   True    1
3   False   2
4   False   3
5   True    3
6   True    3
7   True    3
8   False   4
```